# pip install pybluez2: package directory 'bluetooth/macos' does not exist

Tags: python, pip, pybluez

```bash
→ pip3 install pybluez2
Collecting pybluez2
  Using cached pybluez2-0.46.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing eager_resources to /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/eager_resources.txt
      writing requirements to /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/th/d3gfh4w9027cz6nnj4118g4w0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-sj101jx/pybluez2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      error: package directory 'bluetooth/macos' does not exist
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Using Mac OSX 13.0
2021 Macbook Pro M1 Chip

Python and pip versions:

```bash
→ pip3 -V
pip 22.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

→ python3 -V
Python 3.11.0
```

Comment: I do have exactly the same error message for windows: "bluetooth/windows" does not exist. 
I hope there is some resolution available!

Comment: The only package working for Python 3.11 was: bleak (github.com/hbldh/bleak)

Answer (score 4):

From https://pypi.org/project/pybluez2/0.46/#files:

- Built Distributions: For macOS and Windows, the author only included `macosx_10_15_x86_64` and `win_amd64` for Built Distributions.
- Source Distribution: The author didn't package `bluetooth/macos/` and `bluetooth/windows/` in the Source Distribution.

You can install from the Git source:

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/airgproducts/pybluez2.git@0.46
```